What is this bush and could it be attracting hundreds of flies?

I am located in Southern Ontario and this is right outside my front door. Right now there are hundreds, if not thousands of buzzing around this bush and anything around it. I have checked inside the bush and around it for anything that could be a source of them but cannot find a thing. There are no flies in the house or garage.
Adding that there are no flies during the early morning when the sun has not hit the bush.

It appears to be a Euonymus variety of some sort, most likely E. japonica, and yes, they can attract flies when they flower - its the flowers which attract them. Flies do pollinate flowers like bees do, and this shrub is one of their favourites. Best thing to do is prune it back, either with shears or secateurs, making sure to cut off the flowers. Either that or go through the foliage and clip out each flowering stem if you want an immediate solution, but obviously, the flowers will fade on their own within a couple of weeks.

It might be worth adding that just because these are flies, they are not necessarily disease vectors.
